# How to create a feature map?

Tags: uml, diagrams, notation

I have a big side project that I do now for 3 years. It has a lot of extra small tools to help me do tasks. Most of those tools are so old that I forgot what I have there.

How to create a feature map to have easy reminder of what is possible ?

Is there some special UML diagram notation for it?

How to do it? I think graphic version would be better than a readme text file.

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'mind mapping' software.  There is a great deal of it out there.

Comment: @IAdapter may be thinking of self-organizing maps as described here (http://www.nnwj.de/kohonen-feature-map.html) rather than doing manual analysis and organization that common mind maps require. If the tools have excellent internal documentation, a keyword frequency cloud might be one easy way to understand the tools at a glance. It would take somewhat more involved analysis of the code itself to determine relationships that can be used for composing self-organized functional feature maps.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use mind maps.

Check this link for explanation of the concept
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map

You can hand draw mind maps or use a software.

You can get free software from sites below:

- Freeplane
- Freemind

I have tried both and found that Freeplane has lot of features.